# How can i see the difference between address and value c++ class?

Tags: c++

I have a problem in pointers and reference understanding.
I have the following snippet:

```
class U
{
protected:
    int m;
public:
    U(int m = 0) : m(m) {}
    virtual void f() { cout << "U::f() @ m = " << m << endl; }
};

class V : public U
{
    int n;
public:
    V(int m, int n) : U(m), n(n) {}
    void f() { cout << "V::f() @ m = " << m << ", n = " << n << endl; }
};

int main() {
    V v1(1, 1), v2(2, 2);
    v1.f();
    v2.f();
    U* u = &v1;
    *u = v2;
    v1.f();
    v2.f();
}
```

I run this and the output is:

```
V::f() @ m = 1, n = 1
V::f() @ m = 2, n = 2
V::f() @ m = 2, n = 1
V::f() @ m = 2, n = 2
```

I don't understand the third line of output: `V::f() @ m = 2, n = 1`. Why `m` is changed to `2`?

Answer (score 3):

```
*u=v2;
```

This doesn't make `u` point to `v2`. It assigns `v2` to the `U` sub-object of the object that `u` points to, i.e. to the `U` part of `v1`. This is because `*u` is a `U` object.

Comment: Ok, and then why is 2 1 and not 2 2 if v1=v2?

Comment: @Boolean Because `*u` is a `U` object, so the `V part gets sliced.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it.How can V part to get sliced just because *u is a U object?

Comment: @Boolean If you say `U u; V v;` and `u = v;` the assignment from a `v` object to a `u` one can only assign the `u` part.

Answer (score 0):

first of all 
*u = v2;
doesn't make u point to v2 . first u is dereferenced and it is equivalent to
(U)v1 = v2;

Since class U only contains U::int m so only m is modified using assignment operation.